# Java Dependency Class is unable to access properties via System.getProperty()

Tags: java, spring, maven-3

I have a maven dependency jar that requires access to `-DmyProperty=foo`. When I start my application my main project can access the myProperty value. However the classes within the dependency jar (also a maven project) is unable to access these using `System.getProperty()` and returns `null` value. I was under the impression that every class on the class path had access to these resources. Is there a good way to get these values passed back to the dependency jar? If it makes a difference, both projects are built on spring.

The dependency jar uses:

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

public class myClass{
  ...
  public void myFunction() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("System Env: " + environment.getProperty("myProperty"));
}
```

The main project imports the above project and creates a new instance of the above class and runs myFunction but blows up with a null pointer on `environmnt.getProperty()`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are dependencies in the same spring context?

Comment: Why exactly does it _require_ access to the system property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring @Autowired annotation as below, but make sure you annotate your class with @Component or similar ones.

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

Also make sure your bean is visible for scanning, Component scanning should be enabled like this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="<YOUR_PACKAGE>"/>
```

or

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"<YOUR_PACKAGE>"} )
```

Comment: Ya i have a @ComponentScan in the dependency jar and if i run the dependency jar alone it can access the -DmyProperty. but when i provide -DmyProperty to my service (which imports the dependency jar)... the dependency jar cannot read the -DmyProperty.